# How to highlight rows in grids in Extjs

Tags: extjs, highlight

In extjs how do I highlight a row in a grid, by providing the grid and row details. If not pls provide any other method to do it.

```
mygrid.getSelectionModel().selectRows(array,keep current selections);
```

The above line selects and highlights it in default color. Is there a way to customize its color?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you want to highlight a row by selecting it, or just highlight it without selecting it.

The following article contains nearly everything you should know about ExtJS styling grids: http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells

Under "Styling Rows" it says:

> In many cases the styling for a row is dependent on the data for that row. That data is represented by a record in the store. We can add a CSS class to the  element based on the record using the config option getRowClass:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { 
    ... 
    viewConfig: { 
        stripeRows: false, 
        getRowClass: function(record) { 
            return record.get('age') < 18 ? 'child-row' : 'adult-row'; 
        } 
    } 
});
```

with the custom CSS:

```
.child-row .x-grid-cell { 
    background-color: #ffe2e2; 
    color: #900; 
} 

.adult-row .x-grid-cell { 
    background-color: #e2ffe2; 
    color: #090; 
}
```

Not sure whether this is what you are searching for, but you can have a look at the complete article, I am sure you find the answer to your question in there.

Just customizing the color of selected rows in a certain grid is also completely possible by defining a certain bodyCls on the grid (e.g. `bodyCls:"mygrid"`) and a corresponding custom style:

```
.mygrid .x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-cell {
    background-image:none;
    background-color:#fc0;
}
```

Comment: actually the issue is:   i have a grid, When user edits and saves that grid I do a validation and need to highlight the rows that are incorrect and need it highlighted until its provided with acceptable values

Comment: Well, this should be really easy to do with `getRowClass`. You just have to put the validation logic into `getRowClass` function.